# @react-native-firebase/storage - get url after uploading an image

Tags: react-native, firebase-storage, react-native-firebase

Im trying to find an efficient way to get the url of an image in firebase right after ive uploaded it.
Id like to avoid writing a totally separate function to this....and instead Id like to include it in the promise chain.  See code below

```
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';

storage()
        .ref('path/to/remote/folder')
        .putFile('uri/of/local/image')
        .then(() => {
          //Id like to use getDownloadUrl() function here;
        })
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create chain of promises using `await` and then easily get your download url as below :

```js
/**
 * Upload the image to the specific firebase path
 * @param {String} uri Uri of the image
 * @param {String} name Name of the image
 * @param {String} firebasePath Firebase image path to store
 */
const uploadImage = async (uri, name, firebasePath) => {
  const imageRef = storage().ref(`${firebasePath}/${name}`)
  await imageRef.putFile(uri, { contentType: 'image/jpg'}).catch((error) => { throw error })
  const url = await imageRef.getDownloadURL().catch((error) => { throw error });
  return url
}
```

Now you can call this function as below :

```js
const uploadedUrl = await uploadImage('uri/of/local/image', 'imageName.jpg', 'path/to/remote/folder');
```

Now `uploadedUrl` will contains url of the uploaded image.

Comment: You have to declare your parent function as `async`. for ex `async methodName () => { your code }`.

Answer (score 0):

Good answer from Kishan but did not work for me....below includes some minor modifications so would work for me.

```
const localUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? imgPickResponse.uri.replace('file://', '') : imgPickResponse.uri;

          this.uploadImageAndGetUrl(localUri, '/profilePics/' + this.props.userId)
          .then(url => {console.log(url);}); 
}


  uploadImageAndGetUrl = async (localUri, firebasePath) => {
    try {
      const imageRef = storage().ref(firebasePath);
      await imageRef.putFile(localUri, {contentType: 'image/jpg'});
      const url = await imageRef.getDownloadURL();
      return url;
    } catch (err) {
      Alert.alert(err);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, uri threw an error with Android permissions. So following function worked for me. Instead of uri, I passed response.path from the ImagePicker. Tip: you can use uuid to generate random file name.

```
this.uploadAndReturnFirestoreLink(response.path, 'images/' + 'example.jpg')

uploadAndReturnFirestoreLink = async (loaclPath, folderPath) => {
    console.log(loaclPath)

    try {
        const imageRef = storage().ref(folderPath);
        await imageRef.putFile(loaclPath, { contentType: 'image/jpg' });
        const url = await imageRef.getDownloadURL();
        console.log(url)
        alert('Upload Success', url)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};
```