# How to get URL from firebase storage/react native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, backend, firebase-storage

The main thing i want to get when a user selects a photo from their album is to get a url from that photo that i can use in my users db.  Putting the url to user document in firebase is working and the ImagePicker is working.  My main question is how would i(through firebase storage) get a actual url and not something like this:

> 250F8B0C-72D3-43D4-9CDA-B7F6D8A11F81.jpg

**code:**

```
const [image, setImage] = useState("");
  //functions
  const pickImage = async () => {
    try {
 // No permissions request is necessary for launching the image library
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

   console.log(result);

    if (!result.canceled) {
      auth.currentUser.photoURL = result.uri
      setImage(result.uri);
      console.log(result.uri)
      imgFirebase()
    }
  {/**
  await updateDoc(doc(db, "users", uid, {
      photoURL: result.uri.toString()
    }))
*/}
    }
    catch(E) {
      alert(E)
    }

  };
  async function imgFirebase () {
   const d = await fetch(image)
   const dd = await d.blob()
   const fileName = image.substring(image.lastIndexOf("/")+1)
   console.log(fileName)
   const storage = getStorage();
  const storageRef = ref(storage, fileName);
  uploadBytes(storageRef,dd).then((snapshot) => {
    console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
  });
  const httpsReference = ref(storage, 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/b/bucket/o/images%20stars.jpg');  

  }
```

---

storage structure
[what the firebase storage looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22Dk7.png):
**note that if i press on the image it actually gives me the url in a new tab...i have tried the getDownloadUrl function from the docs but its also giving me errors with the storage reference

in my imgFirebase function what what i need to get to get just the url of the img/blob that i get from the Image picker/firebase storage

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59525278/react-native-firebase-storage-get-url-after-uploading-an-image

Answer (score 0):

This how to get url when image has uploded

```js
 reader.onload = (e) => {
                if (file == null) return;
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Your uploaded picture',
                    imageUrl: e.target.result,
                    imageAlt: 'The uploaded picture'
                })
                const imageRef = ref(storage, `user/profile/${file.nama + user.uid}`);
                uploadBytes(imageRef, file).then((snapshot) => {
                    getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then((url) => {
                        setImageUrls(url);
                    });
                });
            }
```